# main div height issue after inner div

Tags: javascript

I am adding & removing div inside the main div using javascript dynamically. I am using appendChild and removeChild method for this purpose.

Example,

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

If I remove the first div then the space of first div is still there. I would like to remove the space used by first div and need to bring the second div to first position. Please suggest me good way to do this. Any jquery library also I would like to try.

thanks

Comment: post some codes what you've tried so far

Comment: post your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What do you mean by "If I remove the first div then the space of first div is still there"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use remove(). Please see an example below

Try the following code in you `$(document).ready(function(){` function

```
$('.add').click(function (){
      $('#main').append('<div style="height:30px;border:1px solid #CCC;margin:10px;width:30px;">hey</div>');
 });

/** remove a child from a  container **/
$('.remove').click(function (){ 

   $('#main div').first().remove();
});
```

And your Html body will be something like this

```
<div id="main"></div>
<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
```